# How to stop Symantec Endpoint from screwing up my internet connection proxy settings?

Tags: proxy, anti-virus, symantec, symantec-endpoint-protection, endpoint

We have a Symantec Endpoint infrastructure in our organization. Also, the individual computers connect to the internet through a proxy server.

Now, for some reason, the Endpoint client is repeatedly messing up the proxy address setting in explorer. If, for example, the proxy is set to be "10.200.1.10", then after a reboot, or just some time, it's changing to "a&.200.1.10" or "a0.200.1.10", and the user can't surf the web, making for lots of small, annoying support tickets.

Anyone knows how to stop it from doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, the problem went away. Either some GPO setting that defined the proxy address was screwed, or the last update from symantec fixed this, i'm not sure (we did both at the same time). Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Symantec Support? https://www-secure.symantec.com/connect/

I also use Symantec Endpoint Protection and have had all sorts of problems. I don't use a proxy so have not encountered this issue.

If you can upgrade to the most recent version of their software, it may not fix your issue but its the first thing I can think of to try.

Answer (score 1):

Are you allowed to put in a hostname instead of an IP?   You might as a quick band-aid fix just create an 'A' record for "theproxy" that points to 10.200.1.10 and see if it manages to muck that up.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall and reinstall without Network Threat Protection component.